# PHP ImageMagick making images transparent and drawing them ontop of other images

Tags: php, imagemagick, transparency

I am trying to make a program that can export images with another image(that is semi transparent) drawn on top of it. I'd like to be able to control the transparency on a per pixel value for the top image; and do it fairly quickly. Is there something built into ImageMagick to do this? Both of the images will have full opacity when loaded since they are all jpegs.

I guess you could think of it as a kind of watermark, although it would be procedural.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Imagick::setImageOpacity](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageopacity.php) to set the opacity of the watermark first.

Then, use [Imagick::compositeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php) to apply the watermark image on top of your base.

Comment: Thanks. The issue I am having though is that setImageOpacity sets the whole level of opacity, while I would like full control per pixel. I suppose for a base level it works, but I'd like to have gradient opacity and opacity of shapes set etc.